# При создании таблицы с GUID столбцом ошибка ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```sql
CREATE TABLE Passenger (
  2  id_passenger guid not null auto_increment,
  3  privilege varchar(40) not null,
  4  full_name_passenger varchar(200) not null,
  5  age int not null,
  6  sex varchar(40) not null
  7  );
```

> ERROR at line 2:
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: `guid ... auto_increment` - вот Вы это реально КАК представляете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUID это не число, его нельзя увеличить или уменьшить. Хранить его можно в столбце с типом данных `RAW (16)` ([см. описание функции `SYS_GUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SYS_GUID.html#GUID-761E36B4-32DA-497D-8829-3D4653381F9B)). Нелишне такой столбец объявить как первичный ключ.

Заодно, стоит ли для пола (`sex`) выделять 40 символов? Если конечно не предполагаются такие значения: `'замечательныймужикменявывезвгеленджик'`, то хватит и одного символа.

Итого получится:

```
create table Passenger (
    id_passenger raw (16) default sys_guid () primary key,
    privilege varchar2 (40) not null,
    full_name_passenger varchar2 (200) not null,
    age int not null,
    sex char (1) not null);

Table PASSENGER created.
```